# How to use tidyr to gather a data.table by removing columns using the column names' string?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

Seems to have found a bug in tidyr.

I have a piece of code like this

```
 rm(hello)
 a <- function() {  
  dt <- data.table(`*stat*` = c("mean","max"), time = c(11, 12), val1 = c(1,2), val2 =c(3,4))
  hello <- "^(time)$"
  dt2 <- dt %>% gather(dimension, value, -matches("\\*stat\\*"), -matches(hello))  
}

a()
```

But

```
    dt <- data.table(`*stat*` = c("mean","max"), time = c(11, 12), val1 = c(1,2), val2 =c(3,4))
hello <- "^(time)$"
dt2 <- dt %>% gather(dimension, value, -matches("\\*stat\\*"), -matches(hello))
```

works.

The only difference is that one set of code is in a function but the other is not!

Comment: `var` is a function name. Is it possible that trying it with a less polymorphic string might succeed. (And I get no error with your code anyway..) On the otehr hand even with no error it does deliver the desired result. I would have used `[ , grepl(...)]`

Comment: @BondedDust yep. I updated question. the code works outside of a function but inside it doesn't work.

Comment: @KFB posted (but then deleted) what appears to be the answer here--your function is not printing any output because you haven't asked it to. For instance, in its present form, if you simply did `print(a())`, you would be able to get what you needed. Or, add another line that's just `dt2` at the end of your `a()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just adding an answer here to show the function and standalone code have identical results once `dt2` is added to the last line of the `a()` function (as suggested by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 in the comments).

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- function() {  
  dt <- data.table::data.table(`*stat*` = c("mean","max"), time = c(11, 12), val1 = c(1,2), val2 =c(3,4))
  hello <- "^(time)$"
  dt2 <- dt %>% gather(dimension, value, -matches("\\*stat\\*"), -matches(hello)) 
  dt2
}

a()
#>   *stat* time dimension value
#> 1   mean   11      val1     1
#> 2    max   12      val1     2
#> 3   mean   11      val2     3
#> 4    max   12      val2     4

dt <- data.table::data.table(`*stat*` = c("mean","max"), time = c(11, 12), val1 = c(1,2), val2 =c(3,4))
hello <- "^(time)$"
dt2 <- dt %>% gather(dimension, value, -matches("\\*stat\\*"), -matches(hello))  
dt2
#>   *stat* time dimension value
#> 1   mean   11      val1     1
#> 2    max   12      val1     2
#> 3   mean   11      val2     3
#> 4    max   12      val2     4

identical(a(), dt2)
#> [1] TRUE
```